# Why do I need to specify interface in /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have been simply using `dhcpd *interface*` for a long while, and today I found out that in:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server

it says I'm not only need to specify interface on which server should listen in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`, but also I shall start dhcpd with a complicated cmd `service isc-dhcp-server start`.

I searched about those and turns out that some configurations are belong to an old version dhcp3.

So now I'm totally confused, as I can use both two cmds to start a dhcp server; and while I'm using `dhcpd *interface*`without adding that *interface* in`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`, every thing still goes well.

So could you guys help me with two questions:

1,which configuration belongs to isc-dhcp, and others to dhcp3, especially that `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`?

2,if I keep using `dhcpd *interface*`, will it cause any problem in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the start up scripts, running dhcpd as a service is in my opinion the best way to run dhcpd. This means the OS handles startup, stopping and restarting as needed during upgrade of packages, and during boot and shutdown. It also means the OS can restart if dhcpd crashes.

This is *the* standard way of starting services/daemons in Linux, including Debian, RHEL, Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, Fedora and so on.

This does also mean that you have to inform the system which interfaces it should run dhcpd on. This is done, as you already know, with the `/etc/defaults/isc-dhcpd` file.

I can't see any good reason to run it directly like you've been doing. From time to time I've been running ISC DHCPD in the foreground to do debugging, but that's exceptional cases...

In short: unless you have good reasons not to, do follow the philosophy of the distribution. This also makes it easier for someone taking over. If I were taking over a debian/Ubuntu box with ISC DHCPD, I'd assume it was controlled by systemd, not homemade scripts.

Comment: Did u updated your answer? This one is perfect, thank you!

Comment: looks like /etc/defaults/isc-dhcpd or /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd is not in use anymore, as it says that “dhcpd listens *only* on interfaces for which it finds subnet  declaration in dhcpd.conf. It means that explicitly enumerating interfaces also on command line should not be required in most cases.”